# Не выводит матрицу и вектор. С++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, матрицы, вектор

Не могу понять в чем причина. Должно выводить матрицу и вектор размерностью которую задаешь сам. Подскажите ошибку пожалуйста.

```
// Function for simple initialization of matrix and vector elements
void DummyDataInitialization(double* pMatrix, double* pVector, int Size)
{
int i, j; // Loop variables 
for (i = 0; i < Size; i++)
{
pVector[i] = 1;
for (j = 0; j < Size; j++)
pMatrix[i * Size + j] = i;
}
}
// Function for memory allocation and data initialization
void ProcessInitialization(double* &pMatrix, double* &pVector, double* 
&pResultVector, int Size) {
// Setting the size of initial matrix and vector
do
{
printf("\nEnter size of the initial objects: ");
scanf("%d", &Size); 
printf("\nChosen objects size = %d", Size); 
if (Size <= 0)   
printf("\nSize of objects must be greater than 0!\n"); 
}
while (Size <= 0);

// Memory allocation
pMatrix = new double [Size * Size];
pVector = new double [Size];
pResultVector = new double [Size];



// Initialization of matrix and vector elements
DummyDataInitialization(pMatrix, pVector, Size);
}

// Function for formatted matrix output
void PrintMatrix(double* pMatrix, int RowCount, int ColCount)
{
int i, j; // Loop variables
for (i = 0; i < RowCount; i++)
{
 for (j = 0; j < ColCount; j++)
 printf("%7.4f ", pMatrix[i * ColCount + j]);
 printf("\n");
}
}


// Function for formatted vector output
void PrintVector(double* pVector, int Size)
{
 int i;
 for (i = 0; i < Size; i++)
 printf("%7.4f ", pVector[i]);
 printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { 
double *pMatrix=NULL, *pVector=NULL,  *pResultVector=NULL;
int Size=0, RowCount=0, ColCount=0;

// Memory allocation and data initialization
ProcessInitialization(pMatrix, pVector, pResultVector, Size);
PrintMatrix( pMatrix, RowCount, ColCount);
PrintVector(pVector, Size);



 // Matrix and vector output   
 printf("Initial Matrix: \n");  
 PrintMatrix(pMatrix, Size, Size);   
 printf("Initial Vector: \n"); 
 PrintVector(pVector, Size);

 _getch();



  system("pause");
}
```

Когда запускаю программу, я могу ввести размерность, но не выводит матрицу и вектор. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша функция *PrintMatrix* принимает три аргумента:

- сама матрица
- кол-во строк
- кол-во столбцов

По Вашей задумке, если я верно разобрался в коде, функция *ProcessInitialization* имеет аргумент *int Size*, который хранит количество строк/столбцов матрицы. Но дело в том, что вы передаёте копию переменной Size, и при выходе из функции, разумеется, получаете значение переменной, которое было до вызова функции. Вам нужно изменить объявление и реализацию функции *ProcessInitialization* следующим образом:

```
void ProcessInitialization(double* &pMatrix, double* &pVector, double*
&pResultVector, int &Size)
```

Как Видите, я исправил крайний аргумент *int Size* следующим образом:

```
int &Size
```

, добавив ему передачу по ссылке. В результате, после этого исправления, код начинает выдавать результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. А как можно сделать что-бы Chosen objects size было равно только введенному числу? ( в вашем примере только = 5 )

Comment: @Анна это Ваш код? Ведь число вводится с клавиатуры, пользователем. Я вводил число 5.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, но вопрос состоит в том, как можно сделать, что бы после Chosen objects size было только введенное число, без значения 1,000 1,000.., сразу переходила строка на Initial Matrix? (потому что по логике его нее должно быть, не понимаю от куда оно берется)

Comment: @Анна после метода ProcessInitialization у вас две строки: PrintMatrix( pMatrix, RowCount, ColCount);
PrintVector(pVector, Size);. Удалите.

Answer (score 1):

Отследите в отладчике переменную Size: вы передаете ее в процедуру инициализации по значению, поэтому ее новое значение сохраняется только внутри процедуры, и в main() она всегда равна 0 (ваша инициализация в момент объявления).

Используйте передачу переменной по ссылке.